# Toolbar background drawable dynamic height

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

I add drawable as background in my toolbar, but the image stretched it to its own height.

Possible solution is restrict toolbar to 56dp or something, but I don't want this, as it also will be used for extended toolbar with tabs.

I want gradient similar behaviour for it, "dynamic height"

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:minHeight="56dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set your image as textview background. Use `android:background="@drawable/toolbartitle".` and `setTitle("")` in your code.
your final toolbar will look like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbartitle"
    local:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```